# Calculation of Lyapunov Exponent from Time Series

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems

I am currently doing research in non-linear dynamical systems, and I require to calculate Lyapunov exponents from time series data frequently. I found a MatLab program lyaprosen.m that does this for me, but I am not very sure of its validity, as I do not get the same results from it, as some results in some papers. Does anyone have any alternative tools to calculate Lyapunov exponents from time series data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TSTOOL is the state of the art: http://www.physik3.gwdg.de/tstool/index.html